What size shutoff valve do I need for my dishwasher supply?
My dishwasher came with a 3/8" hose. The prior dishwasher had a bigger hose, possibly 1/2". I also found that the water shut off valve leading to the dishwasher is leaking, so I would like to swap it out.
I know it might be hard from a photo, but any chance someone can give me some right sizes on this? I do not have the part in hand. Thanks in advance for your help.



Have you checked where the leak originates, and tried replacing packing or other fix? Unless the valve body is cracked, there might not be need to replace it.

It is spraying from the valve itself, from the handle.

That sounds like repacking is called for. Otherwise, disconnect the valve. Go into w plumbing supplier, hand the valve to them and say "I need one of these", bring the new stuff me home and install it. But you might want to consider replacing it with a quarter-turn lever-handle ball valve, if you are going to replace it; they're better for most cases where all you care about is on and off.

You state, "It is spraying from the valve itself, from the handle." If that is, from around the valve stem, it may be a very simple repair: replace the packing.
The packing is string, wound around the valve stem, held in place by the packing nut. In the fine picture you provided, the packing nut has been outlined in blue.


Get valve packing, such as shown in this search at HomeDepot.
Shut the main water supply valve and drain water above that valve, e.g., flushing toilets. Place rags underneath to catch drips.
Unscrew the Phillips-head screw in the valve handle and remove the handle.
Gently clean the valve with a toothbrush and/or small wire brush.
Remove the packing nut, and remove the valve stem and nut.
Remove the old packing (likely cord coated in wax and graphite).
Apply new PTFE coated packing around the stem. Use enough so that it will be tightly compressed around the stem when the nut is tightened.
Turn on the main valve and check for leaks.

This is far easier than replacing the valve, if the packing is the only fault.

Wow, thank you for the detailed information. Yes it appears to be coming from the handle. I will try your method. I really appreciate the help.

It's actually even easier than that.  You can just buy a valve repair kit.  https://www.brasscraft.com/product/multi-turn-stop-stem-repair-kit/
